# How to zoom all things except some paths / text on an svg canvas without changing its exact position

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-edit, svgpanzoom

I want to zoom all things except some paths / text on an svg canvas without changing the path / text exact position using svgpanzoom js.
The actual working of my needs is something like a map with some markers on it, I also want to dynamically place new pin or markers also ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="640px" height="480px" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
<g id="viewport">
<rect x="27" y="33" fill="#14A0E8" width="134" height="134"/>
<rect x="27" y="167" fill="#8ABB50" width="134" height="134"/>
<rect x="161" y="231" fill="#F97659" width="134" height="134"/>
<rect x="295" y="167" fill="#14A0E8" width="134" height="134"/>
<rect x="57" y="365" fill="#8ABB50" width="372" height="57"/>
<rect x="161" y="33" fill="#CCCC99" width="134" height="134"/>
<rect x="429" y="33" fill="#F97659" width="134" height="134"/>
<rect x="429" y="301" fill="#F97659" width="134" height="64"/>
<rect x="429" y="202" fill="#CCCC99" width="134" height="64"/>
<g class="noZoom">
<path d="M103.912,213.845c0,5.248-6.218,9.378-9.502,14.649c-4.293-5.507-9.501-9.401-9.501-14.649s4.254-9.501,9.501-9.501
S103.912,208.598,103.912,213.845z"/>
<circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="94.548" cy="212.497" r="3.349"/>
</g>
<g class="noZoom">
<path d="M480.912,334.846c0,5.247-6.219,9.378-9.502,14.648c-4.293-5.508-9.502-9.401-9.502-14.648
c0-5.248,4.254-9.502,9.502-9.502C476.657,325.344,480.912,329.598,480.912,334.846z"/>
<circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="471.548" cy="333.496" r="3.349"/>
</g>
<text class="noZoom" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 80.1992 240)" font-size="8">Marker 1</text>
<text class="noZoom" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 459.1992 359.5)" font-size="8">Marker 2</text>
<text class="noZoom" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 201.1992 204.3438)" font-size="8">Some Information</text>
<text class="noZoom" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 325.6992 274.3438)" font-size="8">Some Another Information</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Above shown is an example of the svg that looks like and I am trying to zoom all things inside SVG but the markers and text should be in same place itself without increaing its zooming level

I am using the [svgpanzoom](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom)

Comment: Could you put the elements you don't want zoomed in a different group, and only have the elements you do want zoomed in a different group/svg ?

Comment: The path applied with `class="noZoom"` are the things that should not be zoomed, I want work this like the working of google maps markers, pins and place names

Comment: Not sure if you can do that with that svgpz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done similar thing by adding listener to `onZoom` event. In this listener I've increased font size of text elements and stroke width of paths depending on scale factor. Another way is to have separate group for `noZoom` elements and listen to `onPan` event where you can get new x and y translation and call `getZoom` to obtain new CTM and as result change coordinates of each `noZoom` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can zoom one group element. You can place in it any elements you want. [Documentation](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom#using-a-custom-viewport). [Demo](http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/layers.html).

Comment: I want to keep the position of those groups (markers) according to the svg zoomed or panned.